# Find enames of managers who manage only departments with budgets > $1 million, but at least one department with budget < $5 million

Tags: mysql, sql

An employee can work in more than one department; the pct_time field of the Works relation shows the percentage of time that a given employee works in a given department.

Emp(eid:integer, ename:string, age:integer, salary:real)
Works(eid:integer, did:integer, pct_time:integer)
Dept(did:integer, dname:string, budget:real, managerid:integer)

Here's what I have so far:

```
select ename 
from emp, dept
where emp.eid = dept.managerid
group by ename 
having ename = all(select ename
    from emp, dept
    where emp.eid = dept.managerid and budget > 1000000) and
        ename = any(select ename
        from emp, dept
        where emp.eid = dept.managerid and budget < 5000000)
```

Can someone please help me out with this problem? It seems that I just keep going in circles here.

Comment: Forget about the natural join construction. Don't be lazy, specify the join columns!

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I meant to have cross product in the from clause then join the columns in the where clause. Just losing my mind with this problem. But in general, is it frowned upon to use natural join?

Comment: While I agree that it would be helpful to have data included in my question, I do think that having sample data can make you think you have the right answer when you really don't.  The code should work for any data as the data is bound to change in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude everyone who manages a department with a budget less than 1 million first. A simple solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT e.name
FROM employee e
JOIN dept d ON e.id = d.managerId
WHERE e.Id NOT IN ( SELECT managerId 
                  FROM dept
                  WHERE budget < 1000000)
AND d.budget < 5000000
GROUP BY e.name
```

Here is an example of this working: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83c63/2)

**EDIT**: Here's a second example. I have promoted Bob to the head of HR which has a budget greater than $5m. As you can see, the query still works: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bf57/1)

Comment: This is really close.  Thanks for the visual via SQL Fiddle.  The only thing that isn't compensated for is if Bob handled a budget that was over $5 million then that would be excluded because of the structure of the where clause.  But the question asks for at least ONE of the budgets to be under $5 million.  So there could be budgets over $5 million.  But Bob only has an account for $3 million and $4 million.

Comment: If you're only selecting the name, does it matter? To clarify - if you want to select everyone who manages at least one department with a budget less than $5m, then this should work. If your select statement is more complicated than a name, like say you want to list the departments managed by people fitting this criteria including ones over $5m, then you need to modify your question to specify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: The question doesn't put any restriction on having accounts over $5 million.  But the where clause DOES.  The question asks that all accounts be greater than $1 million which your where clause does address.  But it also asks that only ONE of the budgets be less than $5 million.  Therefore there could be many budgets over $5 million just as long as one of them is under.  You may have to read the question a few times carefully and then what I'm saying to understand.  If you change the budget numbers for Bob to say $12 million and the other to $6 million then that may help visualize the mistake.

Comment: @HR8938Cephei I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean. The query will find the names of managers who manage at least one department with a budget less than than $5m. The number of departments over $5m is irrelevant unless a manager has a department with a budget under $5m, which is what this query picks up. Could you provide an expected output in your question?

Comment: I'm so sorry for confusing you.  I'm really burned out on this stuff.  You're right, those over $5 million are irrelevant in this situation.  I made this question harder than it was this whole time.  I'll mark your answer as the correct one.  Thanks again for your help man.